# Accessing an item for deletion in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am trying to remove an item in a list.
student =[ ['Bob', '95'], ['Gretchen', '90'] ]

my code is as follows:

```
 elif menu == 3:
        # Remove students
        student_removal = input("Please enter the name of the student you would like to remove")
        for s in student:
            if isinstance(student, type(list)):
                student.remove(student_removal)
        if student != student_removal:
            print("The student name you have entered is not in the grade book. Please choose a different option")
```

Instead of it removing the item from my list, it is simply giving me the print statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going about this wrong. I would suggest using a dictionary, if you are going to store key-value pairs. You'd first define a dictionary like this:

```
student = { 'Bob' : '95', 'Gretchen' : '90' }
```

Now, removal becomes simple:

```
name = input(...)
if name in student:
    del student[name]
else:
    print("Invalid name")
```

The advantage of dictionaries is the constant time access to key-values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
student_removal = input("Please enter the name of the student you would like to remove")
if student_removal in student:
    student.remove(student_removal)
    print("Student removed from list")
else:
    print("The student name you have entered is not in the grade b")
```